# How to represents that data in 2 dimensions array using Test-Driven Development?

Tags: java, arrays

Given a 1-dimensional array of objects, create something that represents that data in 2 dimensions.  That is, each element of the original array can now be accessed by a row and column coordinate.

The data from the original array shall be arranged in the new entity sequentially by rows.

The ideal dimensions of this new entity would be square.  If there are not the right number of elements to make a square, the dimensions should be “as close to a square” as possible.

The input array can contain any types of objects, including nulls.

From the entity returned, the client should be able to reconstruct with certainty the size and contents of the original array.

Here is my code

```
public String[][] oneDimension(String[] ar) {
    len=ar.length;
    matrix=(int)(Math.ceil(Math.pow(len, 0.5)));
    index=0;
    String arr[][]=new String[matrix][matrix];
    for(int a=0;a<matrix;a++) {
        for (int b=0;b<matrix;b++) {
            try {
                arr[a][b]=ar[index];
                index=index+1;
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            }   
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

[image]
is there any other way shorter than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any other way shorter than this

Your code uses exceptions for non-exceptional situations - a very bad thing that needs to be avoided for a variety of reasons ranging from readability to performance. Instead of trying to access an element and wait for an exception, the code should check if the index is valid before the access.

Now you can rewrite your program to use one loop instead of two, going by the index of the original array and converting it to a `(row, col)` pair that indexes into the output array:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != len ; i++) {
    int row = i / matrix;
    int col = i % matrix;
    ...
}
```

This approach helps you avoid using an exception for a non-exceptional situation.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i have updated the question with some test data, i need it to be always squared array.

Comment: @Ravi That's even simpler - all you need to do is replacing your two loops with one, and dropping the `try`/`catch`. See the edit.